# VS Code autosuggest

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

VS Code's autocomplete is awesome:

[image]

*after tabbing:*

[image]

However, a lot of times I find myself wanting to insert something to the start of a non-blank line. For example, in the following example I have a variable named 'myVar' and I want to insert the `log` auto-complete:

[image]

Now of course one way to solve this is to enter in 'space', 'arrow-left' and then type in the word, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get an auto-complet that will basically ignore any text that is to the right of the cursor.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in that case you should trigger intellisense yourself with `Ctrl+space` (command is `Trigger Suggest` if you want to rebind it to something else).

Comment: @Mark yes that's it!

Answer (score 1):

create your own rules and stuff.

at the root of your project create a folder call `.vscode` inside add a file `[WHATEVER-NAME].code-snippets` make sure it has the extenssion `code-snippets`

[image]

```json
{
    "clg": {
        "prefix": "clg",
        "body": "console.log(\"$1\", $1);"
    },
    "react": {
        "prefix": "react",
        "body": "import * as React from \"react\";",
    },
    "useEffect": {
        "prefix": "useEffect",
        "body": [
            "React.useEffect(()=> {",
            "$1",
            "},[]);"
        ]
    },
    "useState": {
        "prefix": "useState",
        "body": "const [ $1, $1Set ] = React.useState($2);"
    }
}
```

unfortunatelly it is imposible to ignore any text after.
but for example what I do is I used the snippet from above. when I type `clg` it becomes `console.log('text', text);` then I type what ever I want for `text` and it changes both texts at the same time. you feelme?

for an advanced and customized way go to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

Comment: at the root of your project <-- where would I find the root? Or is it just the cwd?

Comment: add a pic with the .vscode folder and  code.code-snippets

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code settings, search for `editor.suggest.insertMode` and change the value to `insert`:

[image]

Double check that the setting is not "modified elsewhere". If it is, hover over the "Modified elsewhere" text and find where it's different. In my case, the dart language has its own setting for this.

- The `replace` option will replace all text touching the word when you accept a suggestion
- The `insert` option ignores any text to the right of your cursor