# How to wrap a line in console.log

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I find myself frequetly wanting to enclose statements or lines with a `console.log(...)`. For example if I have the following code:

```
let myVar = "Hello";
myVar.slice(1,3);|            // '|' means where the cursor is after typing in the last line
```

And from there I'd like to wrap that line in a `console.log` so it then becomes:

```
let myVar = "Hello";
console.log(myVar.slice(1,3));
```

Is there a short-cut that I can create in VS Code to do this? I have one extension that is supposed to do this but 80% of the time it gets it wrong (for example putting the `)` after the `;` and so I'd just like to do one short-cut command that always gets it right, without having to install an extension. How could I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+q",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "cursorHomeSelect",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)./console.log($1);/}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

That uses the newer built-in command `runCommands` which itself can run multiple commands in a keybinding.

`cursorHomeSelect` first to select from the cursor to beginning of text on line.

`(.*).` Capture the rest of the line except for the last character `;`.  That last matched `;` will not be in capture group 1 and so will not appear within the `console.log...)` body.

Comment: very cool. Where do I put the `keybindings.json` file? Or can I enter it in by selecting something in the Shift-Cmd-P menu?

Comment: Go to `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the Command Palette and it will open the `keybindings.json` file.  Make sure to put the keybinding inside that JSON object's `{}`.

Comment: beautiful, thank you! I just changed it slightly to `"snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*?)(;|$)/console.log($1);/}"` so in case there is no trailing `;` it doesn't shave off the last char.

Comment: by the way, do you know if there's a way to do this? perhaps with a multi-command snippet as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71148594/vs-code-autosuggest -- perhaps adding a space, left arrow then re-entering in the text?

Answer (score 0):

For multi-line selection I suggest enhanced version of Mark answer:

```json
{
    "key": "alt+q",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log(\n\t${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\n)"
    },
    "when": "editorFocus",
}
```